# Overriding Spring-Data-JPA default method annotating with EntityGraph causes QueryException

Tags: spring-data-jpa, querydsl

I'm trying to implement a EntityGraph with Data-JPA, since using `QueryDslPredicateExecutor<T>` exposes the method `findAll(Predicate, Pageable)` the one I need, I tried to override it to annotate with `@EntityGraph` then the troubles began it's throwing :

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: org.hibernate.QueryException: query specified join fetching, but the owner of the fetched association was not present in the select list [FromElement{explicit,not a collection join,fetch join,fetch non-lazy properties,classAlias=appointment,role=com.physioclinic.entity.Appointment.createdBy,tableName=user,tableAlias=user5_,origin=appointment appointmen0_,columns={appointmen0_.createdBy_id ,className=com.physioclinic.entity.User}}] [select count(appointment)
from com.physioclinic.entity.Appointment appointment where lower(concat(concat(appointment.patient.person.name,?1),appointment.patient.person.surname)) like ?2 escape '!']; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.QueryException: query specified join fetching, but the owner of the fetched association was not present in the select list [FromElement{explicit,not a collection join,fetch join,fetch non-lazy properties,classAlias=appointment,role=com.physioclinic.entity.Appointment.createdBy,tableName=user,tableAlias=user5_,origin=appointment appointmen0_,columns={appointmen0_.createdBy_id ,className=com.physioclinic.entity.User}}]
```

When I use the default method the way it's comes nothing bad happens, even using the same `Predicate`, but I can't use EntityGraph, Is there some problem with my implementation or with the Predicate?

Follows the objects in the scenario:

Entity

```
@Table(name = "appointment")
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@NamedEntityGraphs({@NamedEntityGraph(name = "graph.Appointment.default", includeAllAttributes = true,
    attributeNodes = {@NamedAttributeNode(value = "physiotherapist"),
        @NamedAttributeNode(value = "patient"),
        @NamedAttributeNode(value = "care")})})
public class Appointment extends PersistableAuditable<User, Long> {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -4325126792470516159L;

    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd/MM/yyyy")
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "date")
    private LocalDate date;

    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "HH:mm")
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "schedule")
    private LocalTime schedule;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "physiotherapist", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Physiotherapist physiotherapist;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "service", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Service service;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "patient", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Patient patient;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE)
    @JoinColumn(name = "care", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Care care;

    public Appointment(long id) {
        setId(id);
    }

    public Appointment() {
    }

    /**
     * Helpers
     */

    public boolean isSpecialPrice() {
        return care.getPrivateCare() && care.getSpecial() && care.getSpecialPrice() != null;
    }

    public boolean isPrivatePrice() {
        return care.getPrivateCare() && care.getHealthCare() == null;
    }

    public boolean isHealthCarePrice() {
        return !care.getPrivateCare() && care.getHealthCare() != null;
    }
}
```

Repository

```
public interface AppointmentRepository extends JpaRepository<Appointment, Long>,
                                               QueryDslPredicateExecutor<Appointment> {

    @EntityGraph(value = "graph.Appointment.default")
    Page<Appointment> findAll(Predicate predicate, Pageable pageable);
}
```

Predicate

```
public final class AppointmentPredicate {

    private AppointmentPredicate() {
    }

    public static Predicate bySearch(String search) {
        QPerson person = QAppointment.appointment.patient.person;
        return person.name.concat(" ").concat(person.surname).containsIgnoreCase(search);
    }

}
```

Comment: Where you able to find a solution? Having the same problem.

Comment: Sadly I couldn't find a solution, so I just leave it on default

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've faced with exactly the same problem and had a lot of fun debugging the spring source code. **So the root cause is: spring is applying hints on the count query which leads to that error.**

QueryDslJpaRepository.java:

```
@Override
public Page<T> findAll(Predicate predicate, Pageable pageable) {

    JPQLQuery countQuery = createQuery(predicate);
    JPQLQuery query = querydsl.applyPagination(pageable, createQuery(predicate));
....
}

protected JPQLQuery createQuery(Predicate... predicate) {

    JPAQuery query = querydsl.createQuery(path).where(predicate);
    CrudMethodMetadata metadata = getRepositoryMethodMetadata();

    if (metadata == null) {
        return query;
    }

    LockModeType type = metadata.getLockModeType();
    query = type == null ? query : query.setLockMode(type);

    for (Entry<String, Object> hint : getQueryHints().entrySet()) {
        query.setHint(hint.getKey(), hint.getValue());
    }

    return query;
}
```

**And the workaround is:** create a supporting interface to your repository interface and implement it overriding the query creation logic. Here is my midnight implementation **(it is just a prototype which must be improved of course)**.

```
public interface SomeRepository extends JpaRepository<SomeEntity, Long>, QueryDslPredicateExecutor<SomeEntity>, SomeRepositoryCustom {
}


public interface SomeRepositoryCustom {
    Page<SomeEntity> findAll(Predicate predicate, Pageable pageable);
}

public class SomeRepositoryImpl extends SimpleJpaRepository<SomeEntity, Long>
    implements SomeEntityRepositoryCustom
{
    private final EntityManager entityManager;
    private final EntityPath<SomeEntity> path;
    private final PathBuilder<SomeEntity> builder;
    private final Querydsl querydsl;

    @Autowired
    public SomeRepositoryImpl(EntityManager entityManager) {
        super(SomeEntity.class, entityManager);


        CrudMethodMetadata metadata = getRepositoryMethodMetadata();
        this.entityManager = entityManager;
        this.path = SimpleEntityPathResolver.INSTANCE.createPath(SomeEntity.class);
        this.builder = new PathBuilder<>(path.getType(), path.getMetadata());
        this.querydsl = new Querydsl(entityManager, builder);
    }

    @Override
    public Page<SomeEntity> findAll(Predicate predicate, Pageable pageable) {
        JPAQuery countQuery = createQuery(predicate);
        JPAQuery query = (JPAQuery) querydsl.applyPagination(pageable, createQuery(predicate));

        query.setHint(EntityGraph.EntityGraphType.LOAD.getKey(),
            entityManager.getEntityGraph("YOUR GRAPH KEY"));

        Long total = countQuery.count();
        List<SomeEntity> content = total > pageable.getOffset() ? query.list(path) :
            Collections.<SomeEntity> emptyList();

        return new PageImpl<>(content, pageable, total);
    }

    private JPAQuery createQuery(Predicate predicate) {
        return querydsl.createQuery(path).where(predicate);
    }

}
```

Looks like it is a bug and I'm going to submit it to the spring jpa jira.

Comment: Thank you very much for sharing this, I will take a look and save for next projects!